# Rails app using Paperclip running on Windows Azure VM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, imagemagick, paperclip, azure-storage

I have a Ruby (1.9.3) on Rails (3.2.9) app running on a Windows Azure Virtual Machine (using a Ruby-Stack-1-9-3-6-Ubuntu-12-10 image). I can successfully deploy to the VM using Capistrano but have reached a wall when it comes to file uploads and Azure Storage.

I'm attempting to implement the [paperclip-azure-storage](https://github.com/gmontard/paperclip-azure-storage) gem, which uses the [waz-storage](https://github.com/Gabey/waz-storage) gem, but can't seem to get past this error:

`undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass`

I get this error whenever I try to create/update/destroy a Video object (using simple Rails forms). To clarify, I get this error on both my local machine as well as the VM instance.

I know the error is with Paperclip because as soon as I comment out the following code in my Video model everything works:

`has_attached_file :pic, :storage => :azure1`

Following instructions from both gem sources (links above), I've added the following files:

- `azure.yml` (contains my Azure storage account name and access key)
- `storage.rb` (copied from [paperclip-azure-storage](https://github.com/gmontard/paperclip-azure-storage) gem and added to /lib/paperclip)
- `paperclip.rb` (also copied from the paperclip-azure-storage gem and added to the list of initializers)

To cover the basics:

- Gemfile: `gem 'paperclip'` just updated to version 3.4.1
- In the form: `<%= form_for @video, html: { multipart: true } do |video_form| %>` tried with and without the `url` option.
- In each of the environment files: `Paperclip.options[:command_path] = "/opt/local/bin/convert"`
- Schema: verified to make sure the `pic` attachment was added properly to the Videos table

I've researched tirelessly for the answer but I can't seem to find the root of the problem. Is it ImageMagick not properly installed? Is it incorrect placement and/or configuration of `storage.rb` and `paperclip.rb` files? Or is it something else altogether?

Here's the code in my `paperclip.rb` initializer:

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    def self.default_options
      @default_options ||= {
        :styles            => {},
        :processors        => [:thumbnail],
        :convert_options   => {},
        :default_url       => "/rails.png",
        :default_style     => :original,
        :whiny             => Paperclip.options[:whiny] || Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails],
        :storage           => :azure1,
        :path              => ":modelname/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename",        
        :azure_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/azure.yml",
        :azure_container   => "system",
        :azure_host_alias  => "name_of_azure_storage.blob.core.windows.net",
        :url               => ':azure_domain_url',
      }
    end    
  end
end
```

I'll gladly post additional code if required.

Has anyone tried/succeeded implementing the aforementioned gems with Windows Azure? I would love any guidance/suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when you use the format:

```
module Paperclip
  class attachment
    ...
  end
end
```

The internal default options for Paperclip don't get created. It then tries to instantiate the URL generator, which is normally defined in those internal default options, and this results in the error you are seeing.

To get past this, I formatted my initializer as follows:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:processors] = [:thumbnail]
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:convert_options] = {}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:styles] = {}
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/rails.png"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_style] = :original
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:whiny] = Paperclip.options[:whiny] || Paperclip.options[:whiny_thumbnails]
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:storage] = :azure1
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] = ":modelname/:attachment/:id/:style/:filename"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:azure_credentials] = "#{Rails.root}/config/azure.yml"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:azure_container] = "system"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:azure_host_alias] = "storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net"
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':azure_domain_url'
```

This allowed the default options to successfully be created/merged with the options in my initializer, and got me past that error.

Since I'm on a recent version of rails, I ran into errors with RAILS_ROOT and RAILS_ENV next, so I adjusted the above initializer bits to use Rails.root and changed the paperclip-azure-storage to use Rails.env instead of RAILS_ENV.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. This would have never occurred to me. I'm going to try this when I have a chance. I actually switched to Carrierwave and found the implementation significantly easier. Thanks for the response, though, I'll definitely give this a shot as the whole thing was driving me crazy.